# Getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on one build, but not the other using the exact same jar

Tags: jar, classpath

This is a bit of an odd problem, but I'm kind of desperate because I'm all out of ideas and google has reached it's end.

I have to builds on two separate machines going. They both use the same jar (pulled from the same location). Problem is, one is getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError where the other is not.

Pretty much the only reasons I can see this happening is if the classpath is incorrect, problem is they both have the same.

the specific classes it can't find are:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch
..
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/velocity/context/Context
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.velocity.context.Context
```

Sorry, can't post the whole stacktrace for securiy reasons, but just trying to figure this out. Just looking for any other reasons this could be happening if someone has run into it.

Thanks